# Select only some part from array objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects and I want to get a new array with objects that will have only some of the initial values.

```
var obj = [{
    key1: 'someValue',
    key2: 'someValue',
    key3: 'someValue'
}, {
    key1: 'someValue2',
    key2: 'someValue2',
    key3: 'someValue2'
}]
```

I am looking something like Underscore's `_.pluck` but for more than one values that will give me as a result.

```
[{
    key1: 'someValue',
    key2: 'someValue'
}, {
    key1: 'someValue2',
    key2: 'someValue2'
}]
```

Comment: what do you want to do from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple items in object and you want to only keep few, you can use [`pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick).

```
_.map(arr, o => _.pick(o, ['key1', 'key2']))
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6sau1x95/1/)

---

You can use [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) with [`omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit).

```
_.map(arr, o => _.omit(o, 'key3'))
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6sau1x95/)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy with JavaScript's built-in `map`:

Using an ES2015 arrow function:

```
var newArray = initialArray.map(e => ({key1: e.key1, key2: e.key2}));
```

```js
var initialArray = [
      {key1: 'someValue', key2: 'someValue', key3: 'someValue'},
      {key1: 'someValue2', key2: 'someValue2', key3: 'someValue2'}
    ];
var newArray = initialArray.map(e => ({key1: e.key1, key2: e.key2}));

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(newArray, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```

Using an old-style function:

```
var newArray = initialArray.map(function(entry) {
  return {key1: entry.key1, key2: entry.key2};
});
```

```js
var initialArray = [
      {key1: 'someValue', key2: 'someValue', key3: 'someValue'},
      {key1: 'someValue2', key2: 'someValue2', key3: 'someValue2'}
    ];
var newArray = initialArray.map(function(entry) {
  return {key1: entry.key1, key2: entry.key2};
});

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(newArray, null, 2) + "</pre>";
```

`map` calls the callback once for each entry in an array, and builds a new array out of the values you return from the callback. So in the above, we're returning new objects with just `key1` and `key2`.

(I renamed `obj` to `initialArray` because while arrays *are* objects, I wanted to emphasize that we were dealing with an array.)